# How to cast property in nested objects to ObjectId with loopback and mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, casting, loopbackjs

Let's say I have the following model definition:

```
{
  "name": "Report",
  "idInjection": true,
  "trackChanges": true,
  "mongodb": {
    "collection": "report"
  },
  "properties": {
    "resource" : {"type": "String"},
    "date" : {"type": "Date"},
    "people" : [ {
        // Here's where I like to have an id property.
        "role" : {"type": "String"},
        "hours" : {"type": "Number"}
    } ],
    "name" : {"type": "String"}
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Now I want to have id property in each object in people array(to be accessed with like report.people[0].id) and it should be **casted** to ObjectId on inserts and updates. But well, loopback doesn't have an `ObjectId` type and the only way seems to be using relations but then how should the foreign key be?

Is there any way to have the id property casted to ObjectId on inserts and updates?

Update:

I tried using embedsMany, but the id wasn't converted:

Here's my report.json:

```
{
  "name": "Report",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "people" : {
      "type": "embedsMany",
      "model": "ReportPerson",
      "options": {
        "validate": true,
        "autoId": false
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

and here's my report-person.json:

```
{
  "name": "ReportPerson",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "hours": {"type" : "number"}
  },
  "validations": [{
      "person" : {
          "model": "Person",
          "type": "belongsTo",
          "foreignKey": "id"
      }
  }],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

When I try to insert this `Report` using the http API:

```
{
    "name" : "report",
    "people" : [
        {
            "id" : "54c7926e1d621dc65495f069",
            "hours" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

The `id` wouldn't be casted to ObjectId and stays as string on the database.

Comment: Have you checked out http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Embedded+models+and+relations?

Comment: @RaymondFeng I updated it my question regarding that.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat did you have any success with the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone playing with loopback and mongodb hits this one once in a while.
To get around the lack of ObjectId type in loopback:
-one way is to indeed describe a relation using the property as a foreign key, as discussed in this post
-the other way, much cleaner imo is to define the property as an id in the JSON file

see [model definition documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-IDproperties)

for example:

`{
  "myId": {
    "type": "string", 
    "id": true,
    "generated": true
   }
}`

now a request on this property will work either with pass the actuel objectId or its string representation